# Link in code is indistiguishable from plain code

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, css, code

On SO and pretty much any other SE site, linked code is clearly distinguishable from non-linked code:

[image: Example from SO]

But on programmers (and meta.programmers), the two are completely undistinguishable:

[image: Example from programmers]

You have to hover over the link to find out it's actually a link, but there's nothing suggesting that.

I think that the two cases should look obviously differently, probably by making the linked code blue, just like on SO.

Live sample:

text text `Code` text [`Linked code`](http://example.com) text

Comment: Not reproducible on mobile version of the site. Also no repro in the android app

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is the view on an iPhone:

[image: iphone screen]